# What's elementary operation in Computer science?

Tags: terminology

What do Computer Science mean when they use the Term Elementary Operations?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: Time complexity is commonly estimated by counting the number of elementary operations performed by the algorithm, supposing that an elementary operation takes a fixed amount of time to perform. Thus, the amount of time taken and the number of elementary operations performed by the algorithm differ by at most a constant factor.

Comment: An elementary operation is a machine operation that contains no simpler operations denoted in the computer language and every  elementary  operation  that  the  fancy  computer  is
 capable  of  executing  can  
also  be  performed  by  a  finite  set  of  elementary  steps,  operating  on  the  Turing  machine  hardware.

Comment: Elementary operation in CS is basic read and write